# Osakazuki maple propagation

Tags: cuttings, maple, japanese-maple, air-layer

I have this maple and wondering if I can propagate easily from it.

How good are this maples at air layers and rooting hardwood/softwood cuttings?

Generally speaking, would these species yield better results with the first year, second year, softwood, hardwood etc? Does it readily root with ait-layering?

[image]